# Must read books for programming cryptography C applications?

Tags: c, security

Which books are really MUST read for a person who attempts to create a critical parts of application(s) in security field, e.g. driver which are dealing with coding/decoding, firewall, kernel subsystem which rely on checking of rights/policies, a secure mail client, etc.

Are there any specific books covering applied C programming topics in field like this? Like how to design/write secure code, what are the common attacks your program must be resistant to and the like?

Comment: Alice in Wonderland, by Lewis Carroll

Comment: Rebember to always give preference to premade tools and libraries with a good reputation over writing your own. Criptography is a field in which a silly bug can easily hide until a real attacker is really attacking your app.

Comment: Too bad I can't uptick @EmilioMBumachar more than once - that's the best answer to give someone

Comment: @KevinDTimm I added an extra uptick on your behalf (and my own) ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, these are must-reads:

Cryptography in C and C++ - [http://www.amazon.com/Cryptography-C-Michael-Welschenbach/dp/1590595025/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590595025)

Secure Programming Cookbook for C and C++: Recipes for Cryptography, Authentication, Input Validation & More - [http://www.amazon.com/Secure-Programming-Cookbook-Cryptography-Authentication/dp/0596003943/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596003943)

Cryptography Engineering: Design Principles and Practical Applications - [http://www.amazon.com/Cryptography-Engineering-Principles-Practical-Applications/dp/0470474246/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470474246)

Security Metrics: Replacing Fear, Uncertainty, and Doubt - [http://www.amazon.com/Security-Metrics-Replacing-Uncertainty-Doubt/dp/0321349989/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349989)

Security Engineering: A Guide to Building Dependable Distributed Systems - [http://www.amazon.com/Security-Engineering-Building-Dependable-Distributed/dp/0470068523/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470068523) (High-level, management issues, etc.)

The following book deserves honorable mention, although many experts repudiate it these days. However, some say it is the best book on the subject, so judge for yourself:

Applied Cryptography: Protocols, Algorithms, and Source Code in C, Second Edition - [http://www.amazon.com/Applied-Cryptography-Protocols-Algorithms-Source/dp/0471117099/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471117099)